# Kentico forms and dynamic subject line in the notification email

Tags: kentico

I have a simple form with two fields, Subject and Message. The body of my email is fine, but i'm trying to append the subject value in the subject line.

This is my subject line

```html
CEO Direct Message - {%value:subject%}
```

And here is the email

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><strong>Subject:</strong> $$value:subject$$</p>

<p><strong>Date:</strong> $$value:FormInserted$$</p>

<p><strong>Message:</strong><br />
$$value:message$$</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing subject is the field name. Have you tried {%subject%} ?

Comment: That's it. Thanks Zach!

Answer (score 1):

Try this --

```
CEO Direct Message - {$subject$}
```